# Bash count number of numbers

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have several space separated strings:

```
1 -2 3  
1 23 456  
apple 69 b4n4n45 gr4pe5 -420 lol 10101010101 lol
1 23 a99 99a 9a9 -1 -23 -a99 -99a -9a9 --1 --23 --a99 --99a --9a9
```

I would like to know the exact number of numbers in each one of these strings. For the examples above the answers should be [ 3, 3, 3, 4]. I would not like to count strings like `b4n4n45` as "numbers". Only *pure* integer strings should be counted.

I tried using grep and regex:

```
$ echo $string | grep '[0-9]' | wc
```

but that's not working out for me. Any tips?

Comment: Would `-14` be counted as a "pure number"? What about `2.5`?

Comment: -14 would be nice to include if you can. No need for decimals though. The set of integers should do nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Bash count number of numbers

```sh
echo $string | grep -Po '(^|^-| | -)[0-9]+((?= )|$)' | wc -w
```

`wc -w` will count the number of space separated sub-strings in a given input
We can use `grep -Po` (-P for Perl regex, -o output ONLY matching) to match pure number sub-strings

We can use Regex to define a pattern of sub-strings we want to keep:

1. `(^|^-| | -)` Starts with one of the four possible starting conditions
2. `[0-9]+` Contains only one or more integer characters
3. `((?= )|$)` Ends with a space or end of line character,`(?= )` looks ahead for a space character but doesn't match, allowing overlap

Comment: Nice approach, but it isn't handling the negative representations. (e.g. it omits `-2` and `-420`)

Comment: Thanks, I added a "-" to account for negative numbers

Comment: Much improved, but wouldn't the last line of the sample still result in `"69 b  -420  10101010101"`? (the the extra `'b'`?)

Comment: Quite right, whitelisting is a probably better solution for this problem...

Comment: This answer finally matches all scenarios, refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276159/grep-that-works-with-overlapping-patterns#276164 for more info on `(?= )`

Answer (score 9):

Could you please try following(tested and written with shown samples), this should include negative numbers too, since OP has mentioned about integers so I have not considered counting floats. It gives output as `3 3 3` for mentioned 3 lines of samples.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(length(int($i))==length($i)){ count++ }
  }
  print count
  count=""
}' Input_file
```

Comment: That's thinking outside the box, and so far the only one that outputs `3, 3, 3` ++

Answer (score 6):

With grep:

```sh
echo "$string" | grep -Ewo -- '-?[0-9]+' | wc -l
```

- `-?[0-9]+` is just an regular expression: optionally a hyphen followed by one or more digits.
- `-w` is the secret sauce: that's the "word-regexp" option. The pattern is implicitly anchored with word boundary markers. This is what finds only the words that match the pattern. The GNU grep man page says:

  > The
  > test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the
  > line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must
  > be either at the end of the line or followed  by  a  non-word  constituent
  > character.

  That is what [@Explorer is testing explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547906/7552). The `-w` option wraps it up in a tiny little bow.
- then, `-o` spits the matched words out, once per line, and `wc -l` counts them.

with plain bash

```sh
read -ra words <<<"$string"
count=0
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
  [[ $word == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] && ((count++))
done
```

- within `[[...]]` the `==` operator is a *pattern matching* operator that uses bash's [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: I was about to ask if you don't have to set `extglob` explicitly, but turns out you don't have to for `[[ ... ]]` – learned something!

Comment: Using posix `--` returns a `+1`

Comment: Would you mind explaining the different syntax tricks used here. I like the format [explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14526011/explorer) used in their answer, but yours seems more concise!

Comment: The string `"1 55 --1 111"` should result in `3` but gives `4` instead. This solution should exclude numbers that start with `--`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that 4 result in bash versions 3.2, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4, 5.0 => `[[ "--1" == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]` is non-zero

Comment: Oh, the grep command returns 4. Yes, `-` is not a "word" character.

Answer (score 6):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i+0||$i==0)c++;print c;c=0}' file
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
```

**Edit**: After my morning coffee I noticed *pure integer strings* so beware, this one counts decimal numbers also.

Comment: Good solution! Does not quite work for the 4th test case of `1 23 a99 99a 9a9 -1 -23 -a99 -99a -9a9 --1 --23 --a99 --99a --9a9`. Your script is counting strings that begin with numbers but contain letters like `9a9`

Comment: Yes, that is awk's feature, 9a9 is 9 if used as a number. In that case `if($i!~/[^-+0-9]/)c++`.

Answer (score 6):

Perl Solution

```
$ perl -lane ' $c=0;for(@F) { if(/^-?\d+$/) { $c++; } } print $c ' lenna.txt
3
3
3
$
```

or

```
$ perl -lne ' $c=0; while(/\b-?\d+\b/g) { ++$c }  print $c  ' lenna.txt
3
3
3
$
```

Comment: The first approach is great! The second seems to be less accurate. Additionally answer would be much improved if you could explain how/what you did.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU awk for FPAT and assuming your input is only aphanumeric + minus signs as shown in your example:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='\\<-?[0-9]+\\>' '{print NF}' file
3
3
3
```

or with any awk for any space-separated strings:

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c+=($i ~ /^-?[0-9]+$/); print c}' file
3
3
3
```

Comment: don't forget possible `+` signs like `+5`

Comment: @kvantour it's rare to have `+` signs in front of positive numbers and necessary to have `-` in front of negative ones and the OP specifically asked for `-` to be considered so I think it's fine as-is.

Comment: No need to worry about `+`. Great second `awk` solution! Your first approach does not pass the 3rd and 4th test cases though.

Comment: It was designed to work with the test cases that were present in your question when I wrote the scripts, you shouldn't expect it (or any other answer) to work other test cases.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -E 's/\s+$//;y/0./10/;s/\S+/$((&!=0))/g;s/\s+/+/g;s/.*/echo $((&))/e'
```

Remove any white space at the end of a line.

Covert any zero to one (we are not interested in the number only that it is a number).

Replace non-white space by a bash arithmetical expression which returns `1` for a number and `0` otherwise.

Replace white space by `+`'s

Evaluate the arithmetic expression created returning the count of numbers.

Comment: This approach works for the first three test cases, but interestingly enough crashes when processing the 4th test case with `sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "99a!=0"`. Would be interested to see a more robust `sed` solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a single regular expression that can pick up pure integers: `[-+]?[0-9]+`. When you combine this with `gsub`, you get the straightforward solution in awk:

```
$ awk '{t=OFS $0 OFS;gsub(FS,OFS OFS,t);print gsub(OFS"[-+]?[0-9]+"OFS,"",t)}'
```

First off, we use `gsub` to count the substitutions. `gsub(ere,repl,str)` makes a substitution of all substrings matching `ere` and replaces it with the string `repl`. It returns the total amount of substitutions done. This is exactly what we are interested in.

There is however still a problem. You cannot just substitute the count the matches of the regular expression `[-+]?[0-9]+` as this would also count strings like `foo123bar`. To avoid this, we try to replace the integers sandwiched between the field separators.

Field separators, on the other hand are again tricky. They can be regular expressions themselves and the default `FS=" "` matches any white-space. Since the output-field separator is a fixed string, it is best to substitute `FS` by `OFS`. In short, the following would fail when working with a tsv-file:

```
 awk '{t=FS $0 FS; print gsub(FS"[-+]?[0-9]+"FS,"",t)}' file
```

While this is all nice, we still have to take care of one last thing: *consecutive fields*. `gsub` does not match with overlaps, hence we have to duplicate the output field separator.

Imagine `OFS="_"`, then the string `_123_456_`, would lead to count one while `_123__456_` would return two.

Comment: First approach is great! Something not quite right about the second approach. The script crashes with `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near $`

Comment: @Lenna I have updated it. Be aware that the second one should be used.

Comment: Looks like that first command gets the job done! Great solution for `awk`!